# Print error if user doesn't introduce a 3 digit number in C

Tags: c

Im very new to C programming, this is my first question so far because this is the first time I cannot find any response on the forum that may suit for my application.

So: Yes, it is a school exercise but I don't want you guys to do it for me. What I have to do is create a program that will ask a 3 digit number, and sum all the digits from the number.

I have already done that, but I want to go deeper and make it impossible to the user to input something different that a 3 digit number. So far I have this:

```
 include <stdio.h>
  include <stdlib.h>
  include <math.h>
  include <string.h>
  include <time.h>
  include <conio.h>
  include <ctype.h>

  int main()
    {
        int mainnum, secnum, suma, resto ;
        char repetir;
        suma = 0;
        do
                       {
                            printf("Input a 3 digit number: ");
                            scanf("%d", &mainnum);
                            fflush(stdin);

                                if (mainnum>999)
                                    {
                                        printf("ERROR: Number is too big\n");
                                    }
                                else if (mainnum<99)
                                    {
                                        printf("ERROR: Number is too small\n");
                                    }
                                else if (!isdigit(mainnum))
                                    {
                                        printf("ERROR: You introduced invalid characters\n");
                                    }

                        } while (mainnum>999 || mainnum<99 || !isdigit(mainnum));
                        secnum = mainnum;



                while (secnum != 0)
                    {
                        resto = secnum % 10;
                        suma = suma + resto;
                        secnum = secnum / 10;
                    }



                printf("The sum of %d digits = %d\n \n", mainnum, suma);


                if (suma != 0) suma = 0;

                printf("Press Y to repeat, or any key to exit: ");
                getchar();
                repetir = getchar();

            } while (repetir == 'y' || repetir == 'Y');

    return 0;

    }
```

I learned the hard way that "isdigit" function won't work because int is not an ASCII character. I've been looking for hours to find a way to make this work but I cannot seem to get to it.

Any help and corrections are apreciated!

Comment: For starters, check the the return value from `scanf()`.

Comment: `scanf("%f", ...)` already parses the (ASCII) text to an int. It already uses something like `isdigit` by itself. You don't have to check for that. What you can do, like @WeatherVane suggests, is to check the result of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cannot fflush stdin, unless you are using Windows.

From C11 7.21.5.2 The fflush function, fflush works only with output/update stream, not input stream.

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

There are two way to get around this. Firstly you can read the 3 digits as string, and does arithmetic through strings. Or you utilize both modulus operations, %, and division. Hopefully that helps you without just giving you the answer.

Comment: So basically I have to make 3 scans for the 3 digits and check every string is a digit?

Comment: That or just do manipulation using the modulus operator. But those 2 are the easiest I thought of.

Comment: Or input a string, make sure that its length is 3, and that all the characters of the string are digits (yes, using isdigit() )

Comment: BTW: `fflush(stdin)` is allowed in Windows, and it actually flushes the input stream (the keyboard in this case) so no strange keystrokes are present. OP should have placed the `fflush()` call just before the `scanf()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code to test that the number was correctly entered:

```
read an int value
if it worked
    read a char value
    if it worked
        if the char value is newline
            if the int value's range is correct
                print the int value
```

You check "if it worked" by testing the function return value from `scanf()`. See the man page for what that should be.

The reason for inputting another char is to test if the next char was a newline. If the input was for example `123a` then the number will be input correctly but the next char read will be `a` not `newline`. It will also detect if you enter say `123.45` because the next char will be `.`

There should be no need to flush the input buffer - in fact it's in the wrong place and would destroy my second test for presence of next char being `newline`.